# Getting "svn: Repository moved permanently to... please relocate" error when trying to take svn diff/export

Tags: svn

I'm quite new to svn. I'm trying to take diff between 2 directories. Below is my command.

```
export SVNREPO=https://svn_path    
svn diff $SVNREPO/dir_path $SVNREPO/dir_path_2
```

I get the "svn: Repository moved permanently to... please relocate" error which isn't very intuitive. Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you set up your web server to serve the repo?

Comment: @Michael: I did not setup the web server, but what specifically are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. The path was incorrect. Make sure the Repo root is correct.